# How to join 2 or more rows with same values at some column in SQL?

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to make a dynamic **select list menu** in my web page. The **select list menu** show the clock **from 11:00:00 until 02:00:00**. If one or more of a clock is reserved, then clock font will become **red**. First, I insert the first row into my table with IdRsv = RV01 and check the result in my web page. The **select list menu** show the 12:00:00 until 14:00:00 become red. So, the result is fine.

My problem appear when I insert another row after that. The result that I wanted is the **select list menu** showing us both of **12:00:00-14:00:00** and **17:00:00-20:00:00's** font become red. The result that I get is only **12:00:00-14:00:00's** font become red.

I realize that the **select list menu** only read the first row.

Table Name : tblreservation
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| IdRsv | IdRoom |   RsvDate    | StartRsv | EndRsv  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| RV01 |  R003    |  2016-01-31  | 12:00:00  | 14:00:00 |
| RV02 |  R003    |  2016-01-31  | 17:00:00  | 20:00:00 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

The query that I try is only SELECT * FROM table WHERE IdRoom = '$idRoom' AND RsvDate = '$rsvDate'
I am using **for condition** to make the clock option in the **select list menu**.
And inside that **for condition**, I am using **if condition** to make the clock's font which is reserved become red.

The php code is :

```
$sql  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblreservation WHERE IdRoom = '$idRoom' AND RsvDate = '$rsvDate'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo"
     <select name='startClock' onchange='startClockFunction(this.value)' id='sc' class='form-control' required>
         <option value=''>--:--</option>";
         while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
             for ($clock = 11; $clock < 27; $clock++) {
                 if ($clock == 24) {
                      $showClock = "00";
                 } 
                 else if ($clock == 25) {
                      $showClock = "01";
                 }
                 else if ($clock == 26) {
                      $showClock = "02";
                 } else {
                      $showClock = $clock;
                 }

                 if ($data['StartRsv'] == "" && $data['EndRsv'] == "") {
                      echo "<option value='$clock:00:00'>$showClock:00</option>";
                 }
                 else if ($clock . ":00:00" >= $data['StartRsv'] && $clock . ":00:00" <= $data['EndRsv']) {
                     echo "<option style='background-color: red; color: white;' value='$clock:00:00' disabled>$showClock:00</option>";
                 }
                 // if someone reserve room at 22:00:00 until 02:00:00 (example)
                 else if ($data['StartRsv'] > $data['EndRsv']) {
                     $dataEndRsv = $data['EndRsv'] + 24;
                     if ($clock . ":00:00" >= $data['StartRsv'] && $jam . ":00:00" <= $dataEndRsv) {
                         echo "<option style='background-color: red; color: white;' value='$clock:00:00' disabled>$showClock:00</option>";
                     } else {
                         echo "<option value='$jam:00:00'>$jamTampil:00</option>";
                     }
                 }
                 else {
                      echo "<option value='$clock:00:00'>$showClock:00</option>";
                 }
              }
          }
echo"
      </select>
    ";
```

EDITED
[here is the capture of my select list menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3waqt.png) using while condition. Look at where my cursor is hovering. It show that the clock looping is looped twice as the result of query is 2 rows.
The question is how to make my **select list menu** showing us both of **12:00:00-14:00:00** and **17:00:00-20:00:00's** font become red?
Where should I put the while condition?

I'm sorry if my English is bad.
Thanks in advanced...

Comment: Why is there `IdRoom= '' AND RsvDate = ''` in your query? Did you omit something?

Comment: Actually sounds like your problem is at the PHP and HTML+CSS levels. So please post your code.

Comment: @Dunno, actually my query is WHERE IdRoom = '$idRoom' AND RsvDate = '$rsvDate'

Answer (score 1):

Extending on @Dunno's answer. You need to fetch all rows with a `while` loop. Then you need an array `$occupied_hours` to keep track of which hours have been taken:

```
$sql  = mysql_query("
    SELECT hour(StartRsv) s, hour(EndRsv) e
    FROM tblreservation 
    WHERE IdRoom = '$idRoom' AND RsvDate = '$rsvDate'");

$occupied_hours = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    for ($i = $row['s']; $i <= $row['e']; $i++) {
        $occupied_hours[$i] = true;
    }
}

echo"<select name='startClock' onchange='startClockFunction(this.value)' id='sc' class='form-control' required>
    <option value=''>--:--</option>";

for ($clock = 11; $clock < 27; $clock++) {
    $clock = $clock % 24;
    if ($clock < 10) {
        $showClock = "0" . $clock;
    }

    if (isset($occupied_hours[$clock])) {
        echo "<option style='background-color: red; color: white;' value='$clock:00:00' disabled>$showClock:00</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='$clock:00:00'>$showClock:00</option>";
    }
}
echo" </select> ";
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your first if statement inside for loop is useless, because your loop starts with the `$clock = 11` and your are checking if `$clock` is less than 10.

And for your actual problem, as you want to get multiple rows, so you have to iterate through the result of `mysql_fetch_array($sql)` using while loop.

```
$sql  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblreservation WHERE IdRoom = '$idRoom' AND RsvDate = '$rsvDate'");

echo"<select name='startClock' onchange='startClockFunction(this.value)' id='sc' class='form-control' required>
     <option value=''>--:--</option>";
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) ){
    for ($clock = 11; $clock < 27; $clock++) {
         if ($clock == 24) {
              $showClock = "00";
         } 
         else if ($clock == 25) {
              $showClock = "01";
         }
         else if ($clock == 26) {
              $showClock = "02";
         } else {
              $showClock = $clock;
         }

         if ( $row['StartRsv'] == "" && $row['EndRsv'] == "" ) {
              echo "<option value='$clock:00:00'>$showClock:00</option>";
         }
         else if ($clock . ":00:00" >= $row['StartRsv'] && $clock . ":00:00" <= $row['EndRsv']) {
              echo "<option style='background-color: red; color: white;' value='$clock:00:00' disabled>$showClock:00</option>";
         }
         else if ("00:00:00" >= $row['StartRsv'] && "01:00:00" <= $row['EndRsv']) {
              echo "<option style='background-color: red; color: white;' value='$clock:00:00' disabled>$showClock:00</option>";
         } 
         else if ("00:00:00" >= $row['StartRsv'] && "02:00:00" <= $row['EndRsv']) {
              echo "<option style='background-color: red; color: white;' value='$clock:00:00' disabled>$showClock:00</option>";
         } else {
              echo "<option value='$clock:00:00'>$showClock:00</option>";
         }
    }
}
echo"
      </select>
    ";
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

```
$time_slots = [];

$sql  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblreservation WHERE IdRoom = '$idRoom' AND RsvDate = '$rsvDate'");

echo"<select name='startClock' onchange='startClockFunction(this.value)' id='sc' class='form-control' required>
     <option value=''>--:--</option>";

$reserved_slots = [];
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) ){
    if( !empty($row['StartRsv']) && !empty($row['StartRsv']) ){
        $reserved_slots[] = [
            'start' => $row['StartRsv'],
            'end' => $row['EndRsv']
        ];
    }
}

for ($clock = 11; $clock < 27; $clock++) {
    $c = $clock . ":00:00";
    $time_slots[] = [
        'key' => $c,
        'display_time' => $clock%24 . ":00:00",
        'is_reserved' => isThisTimeReserved($reserved_slots, $c)
    ];
}

foreach($time_slots as $slot){
    $style = $slot['is_reserved'] ? "style='background-color: red; color: white;'" : "";
    $disabled = $slot['is_reserved'] ? "disabled" : "";
    echo "<option $style value='$clock:00:00' $disabled>$showClock:00</option>";
}
echo"
      </select>
    ";  

//To check if a time slot is reserved or not
function isThisTimeReserved($reserved_slots, $clock){
    return ($clock . ":00:00" >= $reserved_slots['start'] && $clock . ":00:00" <= $reserved_slots['end']);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the correction and the answer.. i already try put the while outside the for, but the result is the clock loop is looped twice.. so the question is where should i put the while condition.. once again thanks :)

Comment: how are you saving `StartRsv ` and `EndRsv `? for instance, your reservation starts at 01:00:00 and ends at 02:00:00, what values would you save?

Comment: I am using select list menu html tag to make the list of clock from 11:00 - 02:00 in 24 hour format. So, when I save into my table, the values are StartRsv = '22:00:00' and EndRsv = '02:00:00' (for example).

Comment: I have try your code. The result is, my select tag didn't show the list of time. I try to make an option tag for testing. I put the option tag inside the while condition (after if condition), and the option tag show up twice as the row in the table is two. After that, I put the option tag outside the while condition, the option tag show up once, as expected. And when I put the option tag inside the for condition, the option tag didn't show up. Sorry if I'm missing something or don't get what you mean..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error in your php code. `mysql_fetch_array` returns only one row of the result, you have to iterate over them using a `while` loop like so:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    ...
}
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: sorry, i don't know php (but I follow sql tag), I just googled this answer. If you know a better solution then post it :)

Comment: @Dunno, thanks for the answer and help.. as Fabricator said, the clock looping is loop twice..